# app keeps crashing with heroku but works locally

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

My web app keeps crashing on heroku and i don't know the reason.  below is the crash log.  I think it is a problem with redis but don't know why because i set up redis add-on for heroku but app is still crashing.

```
2016-05-04T04:02:50.932588+00:00 app[web.1]: > justinwalker@1.0.0 start /app
2016-05-04T04:02:50.932476+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-05-04T04:02:50.932592+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2016-05-04T04:02:50.932593+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-05-04T04:02:53.119406+00:00 app[web.1]: Wed, 04 May 2016 04:02:53 GMT express-session deprecated undefined resave option; provide resave option at server.js:69:2
2016-05-04T04:02:53.120506+00:00 app[web.1]: Wed, 04 May 2016 04:02:53 GMT express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option; provide saveUninitialized option at server.js:69:2
2016-05-04T04:02:53.188481+00:00 app[web.1]: express is listening on port 80
2016-05-04T04:02:53.206209+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:154
2016-05-04T04:02:53.206227+00:00 app[web.1]:       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2016-05-04T04:02:53.206229+00:00 app[web.1]:       ^
2016-05-04T04:02:53.206229+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-05-04T04:02:53.206231+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
2016-05-04T04:02:53.206232+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:893:11)
2016-05-04T04:02:53.206232+00:00 app[web.1]:     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:916:20)
2016-05-04T04:02:53.206233+00:00 app[web.1]:     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1075:14)
2016-05-04T04:02:53.235064+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-05-04T04:02:53.248722+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-79-generic
2016-05-04T04:02:53.249205+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-05-04T04:02:53.249498+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v5.11.0
2016-05-04T04:02:53.264050+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
2016-05-04T04:02:53.264250+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-05-04T04:02:53.264431+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! justinwalker@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2016-05-04T04:02:53.264590+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-05-04T04:02:53.264765+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-05-04T04:02:53.264928+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the justinwalker@1.0.0 start script 'node server.js'.
2016-05-04T04:02:53.265088+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
2016-05-04T04:02:53.265235+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the justinwalker package,
2016-05-04T04:02:53.265383+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-05-04T04:02:53.265526+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-05-04T04:02:53.265699+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
2016-05-04T04:02:53.265875+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-05-04T04:02:53.265993+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs justinwalker
2016-05-04T04:02:53.266128+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
2016-05-04T04:02:53.266294+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls justinwalker
2016-05-04T04:02:53.266473+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-05-04T04:02:53.271506+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-05-04T04:02:53.271794+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-05-04T04:02:53.271995+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-05-04T04:02:54.463336+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-05-04T04:02:54.477765+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: So, what part of this `Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379` do you not understand?  Also, are you sure your express app is supposed to be listening on port 80?  Usually, a hosting environment tells you want port you're supposed to listen to and their infrastructure maps an incoming port 80 request to your custom port that they told you to use.

Comment: I know redis isn't connecting but i can't seem to fix it.  Also its not really listening on port 80 i changed it on the console log but the change is not being recorded on the following log for some reason.  its almost like all the changes i make in my server.js file doesn't matter. anyway i tried the redis and redis cloud add ons for heroku but neither is working.

Comment: If changes in your file are not taking affect, then you need to solve that first.  You are apparently editing the wrong file or there's something you have to do in order to "deploy" a changed version.

Comment: What is the IP of your Redis server? Does it run on the same machine?

Comment: I figured it out.  The problem was the redis server was set to run on localhost by default.  I just set it to run on the host and port designated by heroku add-on for redis.  Thanks though